# URL rewrite programatically

Tags: magento-2.1, url, url-rewrite

I need to rewrite all my category urls. they are more than 600X so it is not possible to set them one by one. how can i set them automatically?

Comment: what type of rewrite  you need ?

Comment: I want to change my category urls to: categories/slug

Comment: Is store already live? So these would be 302's? Also is categores/ dynamic or would it literally be string categories followed by slug?

Comment: Yes it is live. just by slug